# Object declared for DataOutputStream is throwing a NullPointerException

Tags: java, oop

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


public class Server implements ActionListener {

    JPanel p1;
    JTextField t1;
    JButton b1;
    static JPanel ta1;

    static Box vertical = Box.createVerticalBox();

    static JFrame f1 = new JFrame();

    static ServerSocket ss;
    static Socket s;
    static DataInputStream din;
    static DataOutputStream d_out;

    Server(){

        f1.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        f1.setSize(450,700);
        f1.setLayout(null);
        f1.setLocation(100,30);
        f1.setVisible(false);


        p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(null);
        p1.setBounds(0,0,450,70);
        p1.setBackground(new Color(0,0,102));
        f1.add(p1);

        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("com/company/Icons/3.png"));
        Image img2 = img.getImage().getScaledInstance(30,30,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
        ImageIcon img3 = new ImageIcon(img2);

        JLabel lab = new JLabel(img3);
        lab.setBounds(5,17,30,30);
        p1.add(lab);

        lab.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ae){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        ImageIcon img4 = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("com/company/Icons/Frusci dp.jpg"));
        Image img5 = img4.getImage().getScaledInstance(60,60,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
        ImageIcon img6 = new ImageIcon(img5);

        JLabel lab2 = new JLabel(img6);
        lab2.setBounds(45,10,50,50);
        p1.add(lab2);

        JLabel lab3 = new JLabel("John");
        lab3.setBounds(110,3,50,50);
        lab3.setFont(new Font("SAN_SERIF", Font.BOLD, 20));
        lab3.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        p1.add(lab3);

        ImageIcon img7 = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("com/company/Icons/3Icon.png"));
        Image img8 = img7.getImage().getScaledInstance(15,30,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
        ImageIcon img9 = new ImageIcon(img8);

        JLabel label = new JLabel(img9);
        label.setBounds(400,19,15,30);
        p1.add(label);

        JLabel lab4 = new JLabel("Active Now");
        lab4.setBounds(110,24,60,40);
        lab4.setFont(new Font("SAN_SERIF", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        lab4.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        p1.add(lab4);

        t1 = new JTextField();
        t1.setBounds(5,625,340,30);
        t1.setFont(new Font("SAN", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        f1.add(t1);

        ta1 = new JPanel();
        ta1.setBounds(5,77,425,543);
        ta1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        ta1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        ta1.setFont(new Font("SAN_SERIF",Font.PLAIN,20));
        f1.add(ta1);

        b1 = new JButton("Send");
        b1.setBounds(350,625,80,30);
        b1.setBackground(new Color(0,0,102));
        b1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        b1.setFont(new Font("SAN_SERIF", Font.BOLD, 15));
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        f1.add(b1);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

        try{

            String out = t1.getText();

            JPanel p2 = formatLabel(out);

            ta1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JPanel right = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            right.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            right.add(p2, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
            vertical.add(right);

            ta1.add(vertical, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
            d_out.writeUTF(out);
            t1.setText("");



        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

    public static JPanel formatLabel( String out ){
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        p.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        JLabel label = new JLabel(out);
        label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        label.setBackground(new Color(0,0,102));
        label.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,90));

        p.add(label);
        return p;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Server().f1.setVisible(true);



        String inp = "";
        try{
            ss = new ServerSocket(69);
            while(true){
            s = ss.accept();
            din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            d_out = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

            while(true) {
                inp = din.readUTF();
                JPanel p2 = formatLabel(inp);

                JPanel left = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                left.add(p2, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
                left.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                vertical.add(left);
                f1.validate();


            }
            }



        }catch (Exception e){}
    }
}
```

Error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.io.DataOutputStream.writeUTF(String)" because "com.company.Server.d_out" is null

When I send a message from the server to the client, the client shows the output but that is not seen in the server.
When I send a message back from the client only then the output is shown.

Comment: check if `d_out` has value after this line ` d_out = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());`

Comment: No....I am directly passing a string variable into a method of object d_out in the function actionPerformed......The string variable is local to that function